# Prove independence given a relationship

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I'm reading a [book](http://www.computervisionmodels.com/) on Computer Vision and it has this exercise:

> The joint probability $Pr(w,x,y,z)$ over four variables factorizes as
>   $$
> Pr(w,x,y,z) = Pr(w)Pr(z|y)Pr(y|x,w)Pr(x)
> $$
>   Demonstrate that $x$ is independent of $w$ by showing that $Pr(x,w)=Pr(x)Pr(w)$.

The author is using $Pr(\bullet)$ to denote the probability density function. I have tried all sorts of manipulations using Baye's rule, but alas I can't find the proof. Could you please help?

So far the closest I've gotten was:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
Pr(w,x,y,z) & = & Pr(w)Pr(z|y)Pr(y|x,w)Pr(x) \\
Pr(w,x,y,z) & = & Pr(w)Pr(z|y)Pr(y|x,w)Pr(x)\dfrac{Pr(w,x)}{Pr(w,x)} \\
Pr(w,x,y,z)Pr(w,x) & = & Pr(w)Pr(x)Pr(z|y)Pr(y,x,w)
\end{array}
$$

To complete the proof, one would need to show that $Pr(w,x,y,z)=Pr(z|y)Pr(y,x,w)$, but I don't see how this could be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the Law of Total Probability.

$$\begin{align}\Pr(x,w) &= \iint_{\Bbb R^2} \Pr(x,y,z,w)\operatorname d(y,z) \\[1ex] &= \iint_{\Bbb R^2} \Pr(w)\Pr(z\mid y)\Pr(y\mid x,w)\Pr(x)\operatorname d(y,z)\end{align}$$

Comment: Bingo! Got it. Turns out that using this, $Pr(z|y)$ and $Pr(y|x,w)$ vanish after taking the integrals. Thanks a lot.